# Does desingularization preserve connectedness?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, connectedness, affine-varieties

Let $X$ be an irreducible complex affine variety and $W \subset X$ a variety of dimension strictly less than $X$. It follows from Mumford, Algebraic Geometry I, Corollary 4.16 that $X \backslash W$ is connected in the Euclidean topology. Let $g: X' \rightarrow X$ be a desingularization of $X$.

Is it true that $g^{-1}(X \backslash W)$ is connected?

Comment: This is false without some adjustment: take $X=\Bbb C$, $Y=\Bbb R$, and $g=id$. Then the removal of $Y$ disconnects $X$.

Comment: Thank you! Could you tell what kind of adjustments would be needed? What I need is the case when $Y=X-W$ and $W\subset X$ is a variety of dimension strictly less than $X$.

Comment: With those conditions, this statement is true - please make an [edit] to your post to include those conditions and I'll write you an answer.

Comment: Thanks. Have updated the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is true. As $g$ is birational, $X'$ is irreducible; as $g^{-1}(X\setminus W)=X'\setminus g^{-1}(W)$, if we can see that if the closed subset $g^{-1}(W)$ of $X$ is a proper subset of $X'$ then we can apply the same result of Mumford you record in your question to see that $X'\setminus g^{-1}(W)$ is connected. But this follows from birationality of $g$ and irreducibility of $X$: $g$ is an isomorphism on some open subset of $X\setminus W$, and in particular there is some point of $X'$ not in $g^{-1}(W)$.

Comment: Thank you! To clarify: the results for desingulirization are usually stated using schemes and schemes are not necessarily embeddable. Is it still ok to apply the result by Mumford?

Comment: Yes: run it on each affine open patch. As $X'$ is irreducible, every two affine open patches meet, and now you have a union of connected sets that all pairwise intersect. That's connected.